# Windows Installer from .Net 2.0 Custom Action to .Net 4.0 Custom Action - BadImageFormatException

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-2.0, windows-installer, upgrade

I'm having a problem with an application that I recently upgraded from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.0.  During installation, the custom action starts to execute and throws an error.

=== Logging started: 9/30/2011  2:34:09 ===
Error 1001. Error 1001. Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\MyPath\MyCustomAction.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded..
=== Logging stopped: 9/30/2011  2:34:30 ===

Note that should I uninstall the old version of the application first, then install the new version of the application, the installation succeeds without error.

The only thing I can guess is that the .Net 2.0 custom action is failing to be loaded by Windows Installer as it's not the same .Net 4.0 framework as used by the latest version of my application.  Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1):

You've got to set the condition for the runtime in the vdproj (it doesn't update with your custom action project):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0ke5xt.aspx

In Solution Explorer, click the Setup project.

On the View menu, point to Editor, and then click Launch Conditions.

Click .NET Framework.

In the Properties window, change the Version property to the version of the .NET Framework that you want the Setup project to check for and install.

Comment: I have the default .net Framework custom action already added.  Targeting the .Net 4.0 Client Profile framework (i've tried non-client profile .Net 4.0 framework as well).  The Launch Condition doesn't throw any errors during installation.  It's not until the custom action starts to execute that the error occurs.  I've read the content from the link you provided, even trying to tweak the MSI via ORCA.  Still can't get this to work.  Does anyone have experience with upgrading Applications that previously had a .Net 2.0 custom action with a .Net 4.0 custom action?

Comment: So, you're 100% sure the condition for the runtime required version is set to .NET 4.0 in the required version (NOT the pre-requisite)? I've encountered this exact same error time and again after updating custom actions to 4.0 and this has always been the issue.

Comment: Since I install from the MSI, the pre-reqs are not being evaluated (at least last I knew about windows installers).  If I click on my setup project, I go to the Launch Conditions Icon, and under Requirements on Target Machine I have the Search Target Machine node that is empty (has nothing in it), and I have the Launch Conditions node which has 1 item under it.  .Net Framework.  The properties of that .Net Framework Launch Condition is:  Name: ".Net Framework", InstallURL: "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=76617", Message: "[VSDNETMSG]", and Version: ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile".

Comment: Note that the Custom Action library only has references to .Net framework components and one of my other custom libraries.  That other custom library is a part of the same Solution and is also set to compile against the .Net 4.0 Client Profile framework.

Comment: And the Custom Action is set to .NET 4.0 Client Profile (not full)?

Comment: Under Advanced Compile Options of my Custom Action, I have "Generate serialization assemblies = Auto", "Target CP = AnyCPU", "Target framework (all configurations) = .Net Framework 4 Client Profile"

Comment: my one other custom library is also set using the same Advanced Compile Options.

Comment: some extra info here, the currently installed version of this application was built on .Net 2.0 (sp1 I think).  The version I'm installing is a .Net 4.0 version (.Net 4.0 Client Profile).

Comment: New Info:  I just removed the custom action, attempted to upgrade, and got a new error:  "Error 1001.  An exception occurred while uninstalling.  This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will continue.  However, the application might not be fully uninstalled after the uninstall is complete.  -->  Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly.NameSpace, Version=1.2.3.0, culture=neutral, ...".

Comment: so i guess my question now is, why is the uninstall portion of this process trying to load my old .Net 2.0 library?

Comment: When you did the install, it loaded the custom action assembly to disk. It uses that same custom action assembly on uninstall (not the new one you're installing with)

Comment: So i guess my question is how do I get the old custom action to execute so the uninstall is successful?

Comment: how are you executing the uninstall? are you doing a major upgrade path?

Comment: The uninstall is being executed by the msi file.  This is a standard windows setup project.  I think the answer to your question is yes a Major Upgrade Path but I'm not entirely sure what you mean by Major Upgrade Path so i'm not sure.

Comment: The only way afaik that the msi will do an uninstall an old version for you is if you do a  major upgrade which means setting the upgrade code to the current product code and changing the product code. Can you try renaming the custom action dll?

Comment: it's giving errors on more than just the custom action.  I removed the custom action and then the installer gave an error on one of my other custom libraries.  I don't know that this is a major install but we only change the code that auto-changes when you change the version of the installer.  I "think" it's the upgrade code that changes but i've done it so much in the past few years on auto-pilot I don't recall for sure.  We don't manually change either the Product or the Upgrade Codes.

Comment: Blah.  So i'm still stuck on this one and it looks like I'm going to have to create an App just to do the uninstall prior to installing the updated version.  Not really a great solution but at least, if I can figure it out, it'll be progress.  Thanks Microsoft...